# Applescript + Xcode - Read var from cli output and insert into text filed

Tags: xcode, applescript

I have the following AppDelegate.applescript in Xcode. I created a Interface to go with it, and all the code in the script (and the UI) works just fine. But notice the version of the server at the bottom of the UI (image in the link bellow). Right now that is hardcoded.

I wanted to make it dynamic, reading the output of a `httpd -v |grep version`, which can be something like `Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Unix)`.

In other words, I want to be able to `do shell script "/usr/local/bin/httpd -v |grep version"` and display the result in some kind of text cell (or some other cell) in the UI. I can provide the project if makes it easier. Thanks in advance!

[UI of the App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujjol.png)

```
script AppDelegate

#### PROPERTY LIST ####
    property parent : class "NSObject"
    property startApache : missing value
    property restartApache : missing value
    property stopApache : missing value
    property editConfig : missing value
    property editVHosts : missing value
    property openDir : missing value
    property resetConfig : missing value

#### APACHE CMDs ####
    on startApache_(sender)
        do shell script "/usr/local/bin/apachectl start" with administrator privileges
    end startApache_

    on restartApache_(sender)
        do shell script "/usr/local/bin/apachectl restart" with administrator privileges
    end restartApache_

    on stopApache_(sender)
        do shell script "/usr/local/bin/apachectl stop" with administrator privileges
    end stopApache_

    on editConfig_(sender)
        do shell script "open -a /Applications/BBEdit.app /usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4/httpd.conf"
    end editConfig_

    on editVHosts_(sender)
        do shell script "open -a /Applications/BBEdit.app /usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf"
    end editVHosts_

    on openDir_(sender)
        do shell script "open /usr/local/var/www/htdocs/"
    end openDir_

    on resetConfig_(sender)
        display dialog "Are you sure you want to reset the httpd.conf to it's default settings?\n\n This cannot be undone!" with icon stop with title "Reset Configuration File"
        do shell script "/usr/sbin/apachectl stop" with administrator privileges
        do shell script "cp /usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4/httpd.conf.default /usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4/httpd.conf ; cp /usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf.default /usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf" with administrator privileges
    end resetConfig_


    on applicationWillFinishLaunching_(aNotification)
    end applicationWillFinishLaunching_

    on applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed_(sender)
        return true
    end applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed_

    on applicationShouldTerminate_(sender)
        return current application's NSTerminateNow
    end applicationShouldTerminate_

end script
```

Comment: Assign the result of the `do shell script` line to a variable, connect the text field to a property in the script and set its `stringValue` to the variable.

Comment: I don't know what I am doing wrong. Not even: set my Outlet to "this is some text" is working.

Comment: set httpdVersion's stringValue() to "this is some text" \also not working

Comment: Nevermind. I got it. I was placing the code in the wrong place. The string was then:     httpdVersion's setStringValue_(do shell script "/usr/local/bin/httpd -v | grep version")

Answer (score 0):

As vadian mentioned link the textfield and:

```
property httpdVersion : missing value

httpdVersion's setStringValue_(do shell script "/usr/local/bin/httpd -v | grep version")
```